# How to call new order email template for one Product only rest should default

Tags: magento-1.9, email-templates, sales-order

How do you call a new order email template for one Product only rest of the Product should trigger default order email template?

Comment: In this block : if($match){ $templateId = Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAI_SPECIAL_TEMPLATE, $storeId); $customerName = $this->getBillingAddress()->getName(); } How can I create this template - **XML_PATH_EMAI_SPECIAL_TEMPLATE** Please help
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this. For this you need  rewrite model class `Mage_Sales_Model_Order`  and  the function `queueNewOrderEmail` is responsiable for set email template.

```
<global>
    <models>
        <sales>
            <rewrite>
                <order>MyModuleNameSpace_Mymodules_Model_Sales_Order</order>
            </rewrite>
        </sales>
    </models>
</global>
```

You can see  at this function magento `send different email templates basic customer type guest and register`.

```
 // Retrieve corresponding email template id and customer name
        if ($this->getCustomerIsGuest()) {
            $templateId = Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_GUEST_TEMPLATE, $storeId);
            $customerName = $this->getBillingAddress()->getName();
        } else {
            $templateId = Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_TEMPLATE, $storeId);
            $customerName = $this->getCustomerName();
        }
```

So there you need to check your order have contain this `particalur item` then `send your special email template` and check product by sku. Check by attribute is better idea

```
<?php
class MyModuleNameSpace_Mymodules_Sales_Order extends Mage_Sales_Model_order
{
    const XML_PATH_EMAI_SPECIAL_TEMPLATE         = 'sales_email/order/special_template';


    public function queueNewOrderEmail($forceMode = false)
    {
        ......
        /* add this code */
        $items =$this-->getAllItems(); 
        $match=false;
        foreach ($items as $itemId => $item)
        {
            if( $item->getSku()=='YOUR_SPECIAL_PRODUCT'){       
            $match=true;
            }

        }


        // Retrieve corresponding email template id and customer name
        /* this conditions */
        if($match){
            $templateId = Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAI_SPECIAL_TEMPLATE, $storeId);
            $customerName = $this->getBillingAddress()->getName();

        }
        elseif($this->getCustomerIsGuest()) {
            /* change if to else if  */
        //if ($this->getCustomerIsGuest()) {
            $templateId = Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_GUEST_TEMPLATE, $storeId);
            $customerName = $this->getBillingAddress()->getName();
        } else {
            $templateId = Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_TEMPLATE, $storeId);
            $customerName = $this->getCustomerName();
        }

    ....

        return $this;
    }



}
```

Comment: Thank Amit but how to check my product here ?

Comment: by sku you can checlk... also update answer

Comment: I am using the checkout session to get cart products but its not working then how to get

Comment: Do not need used check session

Comment: then how we will get products information